Need a solution on this pl/sql anonymous block
There is one staging table (temp_trans_stable) from the table i need to  transfer the date column to transaction main table. I've written the pl/sql anonymous block. but it shows some error. help me out
DECLARE
    temp_date temp_trans_stable.date%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR temp_rec IN (SELECT trans_number, date FROM temp_trans_stable) LOOP
        BEGIN
            UPDATE certificate
            SET date = temp_rec.date
            WHERE trans_number = temp_rec.trans_number;
            
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Transaction number ' || temp_rec.trans_number || ' not found in transaction table.');
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error updating Transaction number ' || temp_rec.trans_number || ': ' || SQLERRM);
        END;
    END LOOP;
    
    COMMIT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date updated successfully.');
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 5, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:
100p
The symbol "loop" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.
06550. 00000 - "line &s, column ts: nts"
*Cause:
Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:


Is the column really named DATE or did you confuse the column name with the data type? Since DATE is a reserved word, you would need to use double quotes to reference such a column name. But it is probably better to use a different name instead.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question and [ask] both apply here. Your code is incomplete, and so is the error message, and your title conveys nothing about what the question is about.

Can you include create table statements for a minimal reproducible example ? When I run this code (as is) I get PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification because of the column named "date". "date" is a reserved word


DATE is a reserved word and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier.
UPDATE statements do not raise NO_DATA_FOUND exceptions; they just update zero rows.
Using loops and multiple DML statements is usually less performant than using a single DML statement (as it has to write much less to the log files).

You can simplify all the UPDATEs to a single MERGE statement and then loop to find the missing transaction numbers.
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO certificate c
  USING temp_trans_stable t
  ON (c.trans_number = t.trans_number)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET "DATE" = t."DATE";

  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Date updated successfully.');

  FOR r IN (SELECT trans_number
            FROM   temp_trans_stable t
            WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                               FROM   certificate c
                               WHERE  t.trans_number = c.trans_number)
           )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      'Transaction number ' || r.trans_number || ' not found in transaction table.'
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE certificate (trans_number, "DATE") AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE temp_trans_stable (trans_number, "DATE") AS
SELECT 1, DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '1990-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, DATE '2020-01-01' FROM DUAL;

Then the output from the PL/SQL block is:
Date updated successfully.
Transaction number 5 not found in transaction table.

fiddle
